# Write multiple non adjacent cells at once

Tags: excel, vba

I might need some help for a simple problem :
I want to write in various non adjacent cells using a single line code.
The purpose is to write 1 time N cells instead of N times 1 cell to go faster.

I know that using adjacent cells in a given range is working, but I don't want to write in each columns of the same line.

This is the code that I write but is not getting what I want :

```
Dim myRange As Range
arr = Array(1, 2, 3)
Set myRange = Union(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 3))
myRange = arr
```

Result of this code

[image]

What I want is that the second cells of my range (1,3) get the second value of my array (2), not the first or third one.

What I want

[image]

Is there a solution ? Or I will have to write in each cell step by step like :

```
Cells(1,1)=arr(0)
cells(1,2)=arr(1)
```

Comment: I don't think you can do it in one line, and in fact would have to reference the areas. If you try `myrange.cells(1,2)` which cell do you get?

Comment: I agree with SJR, one line is unlikely.  You might have to loop through Areas. I encountered similar problem before and ended up double looping. My q/a may (or may not) offer information:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60006784/extract-split-multiple-ranges-from-range-area-method-when-it-returns-original-ra

Comment: Well ,thanks to both of you. It seems that VBA is a non optimized language aha. I sadly do it cells by cells then.